# devtools: Open response HTML in new tab

Tags: django, google-chrome-devtools

If an ajax/fetch request fails, my framework (django) displays a nice debug page, which contains a lot of useful information.

In chrome devtools I can see a preview of this debug page. But the window in the devtools is way too small.

[image: open-response-in-new-tab]

Is there a way to open the output of the **POST** request in a new tab?

If I use right-button-click "open in new tab" then chrome does a GET. But the GET does not trigger the exception which I would like to debug.

Comment: FYI: You will be able to see the error traceback in (Django) server console

Comment: @JPG thank you. In the server console I only see text. I would like to expand/collapse things like on the debug page (html).

Comment: What about just saving the response as an HTML doc and opening it in a new tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the full-screen mode of dev tools instead of opening in the separate browser tab?

1. Click on the three dots on the right-hand side of the chrome dev tools
2. Click on the first option (the two overlapping squares) and it would open the chrome dev tools in the full-screen mode.

Please refer to the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think the best you can do is recreate the scenario in [Postman](https://www.postman.com). Postman has a tool called [interceptor](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/capturing-request-data/interceptor/) which syncs cookies and [captures requests](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/capturing-request-data/interceptor/#capturing-requests) from Chrome.

Postman interceptor uses a [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo?hl=en) which sends the captured requests to Postman app if you enable interceptor from the app.

[image]

But there could be security risk that the chrome extension will have Site access to all pages, maybe you can limit it by limiting the site access from extension settings(from settings>extensions>Postman interceptor):

[image]

**Alternativly**, if you do not want to use interceptor, then you can copy the payload(form data) and request headers from `Headers` section, then put them in Postman and make a request. Or you can use [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/) library to do the same.